# Why isallnum() in python returns "True" for string containing digits "123"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a starter at python. I've tried some code to understand how isalnum() works. While playing with ide i realized that isalnum() returns True even if string contains only digits.

Below is the code i've tried.

```
string = '123'
print(string.isalnum())
```

MY thinking :
   the above code is expected to return "False" since, string contains only digits not alphanumeric character. Instead it returns "True".

Comment: Alpha**numeric**. That includes numbers.

Comment: You should probably read the documentation for [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum), it doesn't check what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str.isalnum` method tests of all the characters in the given string are either alphabets *or* numbers, not if the string consists of both alphabets and numbers.

If you want to check if a string consists of both alphabets *and* numbers, you should test them separately using the `any` function with generator expressions instead:

```
string.isalnum() and any(c.isalpha() for c in string) and any(c.isdigit() for c in string)
```

Comment: then how is this done to check for alphanumeric character.